# Overlay image on part of <div> border

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` with a uniform `border: 15px`

The jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/user1212/e7Gez/2/

I am trying to get the image to appear on the top left portion of the `<div>`

However the existing `border` is blocking it.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Is this one of your image?   What I would like to know is if you could make it as png and make some invisibility to it?

Comment: Because I have one solution, but if you can`t remove the white from the image it will hide the text under it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can make this Image png of gif and make the white invisible here is my solution

Add Image tag with this PNG or GIF above the div with the class Container

```
<img id="cornerLeft" src="http://smitra.net76.net/post-bg.jpg" />
<div class="content">
   Text Goes here
</div>
```

Then for the style, just use Absulute positionning and the **content** will place itself under that image.

```
#cornerLeft{
    position:absolute;
}
```

And I also remove the background with the picture on it from your **content** class

```
background: #ffffff url('http://smitra.net76.net/post-bg.jpg') no-repeat top left;
```

Comment: Note that I just remove the Widht and Height I put earlier, I forget to remove it on my side.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you need that to be a background, but this would be my attempt at it.

html

```
<div class="content">
    <img src="http://smitra.net76.net/post-bg.jpg" />
    Text Goes here
</div>​
```

css

```
img {
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;    
}
```

Since it looks like you don't actually need it to be a background, but something for corners of the div?

Comment: In my case it would be img { position:relative; top:-15px; left:-15px; }  but the concept works.

Comment: changed it just so it matches